# Why my click is not working on mobileEmulation?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, mobileemulation

I'm testing a web application. I use Selenium + Java. I want test the same thing on desktop and mobile. The tests on desktop are alright, but when I use mobileEmulation (Nexus 5) and do the same test on one site the test is falling. The logs say that the web driver make the click (no errors), but that's not really done. I clicked without no problem the next site, but when I want to click the previous it cannot be done.

I tried different waitings, like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(element));
```

or:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Different selectors:

```
 @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/section[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]")

 @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Poprzednia')]")

 @FindBy(css = "body.indexpage:nth-child(2) section.content_wrap.container-fluid:nth-child(2) main.content_data.col-md-12 div.content_data div.dataTables_wrapper.form-inline.dt-bootstrap.no-footer:nth-child(2) div.row:nth-child(3) div.col-sm-7 div.dataTables_paginate.paging_simple_numbers ul.pagination li.paginate_button.previous:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
```

Different clicks:

```
this.element.click();

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(poprzedniaStrona).click(element);
builder.perform();
```

I think that the problem is becasue the style (text-align) of the site is changing. I tired to change it like on the deskop version, but that does't work:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;')", test1);
```

where:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable_paginate']")
WebElement test1;
```

HTML (The element that I want to click):

```
<a href="#" aria-controls="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" style="">Poprzednia</a>
```

HTML (The element with different style):

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable_paginate"><ul class="pagination"><li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable_previous" style=""><a href="#" aria-controls="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" style="">Poprzednia</a></li><li class="paginate_button active"><a href="#" aria-controls="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li><li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a></li><li class="paginate_button next" id="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="sg-datatables-pllistypl_datatable" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">Następna</a></li></ul></div>
```

**Browser:** Chrome 75

**ChromeDriver:** 75.0.3770.90

I would be very grateful for help :)

[image: Correct SS]

Comment: It looks like previous button is disabled. selenium works only on enabled elements.

Comment: Ups, I paste wrong ss. The right one is not disabled.

Comment: Try using the another strategy like: `partialLinkText('Poprzednia')`Or `linkText('Poprzednia')`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error